# Why does it seem to take less to enchant the weapon which kills the god who is more powerful?

Tags: the-magicians

In S2E12, Kady kills John Gaines in order to harness his demi-god powers, binding them in a piece of metal "powerful enough to kill a god" (in this case a single bullet), intended to kill Raynard the Fox.

In S2E13, Margo enchants a sword, with only a few words and hand movements, which is also capable of killing a god, in this case Ember.

Even though Raynard and Ember are both gods, it's clear that Ember is much, much more powerful than Raynard, yet it takes much less power to enchant the metal that can kill him.

Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: Since this did not happen in the book,  I'm going to hazard a guess. Raynard is a god in our world while Ember is a god in Fillory. When Ember is killed, he was quite weak.

Answer (score 1):

In S2E13, Ember kills Umber. And Julia (not Margo) harnesses the power from the dying breath of Umber to enchant the sword with the power needed to kill a God.

It was exactly the same thing as they did with John Gaines.